# El comando cron:run de cron/cron-bundle no se ejecuta

Tags: symfony, crontab

He instalado cron/cron-bundle en una aplicación symfony 6.2 para ejcutar algunas tareas programadas, pero no se ecuta la tarea del bundle encargada de "correr" los commands configurados.

En el archivo contrab (/etc/crontab) del SO he agregado la línea:

```
* * * * * www-data /usr/bin/php -d memory_limit=128M /home/sistemas/authmanager/bin/console cron:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

como explica la documentacion del bundle, pero hasta que no le hago `cron:start` realmente no inicia el procesamiento de las tareas habilitadas.

Alguna idea???, solo se me ocurre desechar el bundle y crear tareas en el cron para cada uno de los Commands a ejecutar según programación planificada.

Comment: En _cuál_ archivo hiciste qué cambio y cómo lo hiciste?

Comment: @Alfabravo la línea de la tarea programada del bundle, la agregué a /etc/crontab

Comment: Eso no va a funcionar porque el daemon no va a leer el archivo sin más. Ahí debes usar `crontab -e` y editar la configuración. O, mejor, usar los directorios comodín `/etc/cron.hourly`, weekly, daily, etc para no meterle mano a la configuración principal....

Comment: @Alfabravo, ok lo hago así entonces y comento.

Comment: @Alfabravo agregando la línea de cron propia del bundle cron/cron-bundle, mediante crontab -e no funciona, es lo mismo que escribir directamente la línea en el fichero /etc/crontab. Es decir no inicia la ejecución de las tareas planificadas por el bundle, hasta que en la consola no haga un cron:start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya me ha funcionado, agregando la tarea (a sugerencia del usuario @alfabravo) del cron/cron-bundle en un fichero del directorio `/etc/cron.d/` y no editado el cron del usuario root que era lo que estaba haciendo.

De esta manera queda el fichero `/etc/cron.d/authmanager` de la siguiente forma:

```
    SHELL=/bin/bash
    PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
    # tarea principal de cron-cron-bundle
    * * * * * www-data /home/sistemas/authmanager/bin/console cron:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1 --env=prod
    # esta tarea borra los registros de las tareas ejecutadas, anteriores a 1 día.
    0 0 * * * www-data /home/sistemas/authmanager/bin/console cron:reports:truncate 1 > /dev/null --env=prod
```

Agregué una segunda tarea propia de bundle, para que borre de la base de datos los reportes de las ejecuciones de las diferentes tareas anteriores a 1 día.

De esta manera se evitan además posibles problemas de permisos sobre los directorios de la aplicación web, al ejecutarse la tarea programada con el usuario www-data